# Eclipse Makefile: Make Variables are skipped

Tags: eclipse, makefile

I have a project with a Makefile in it, on Unix console it works fine, compiles, builds and I can run the binary at the end.

I imported the project into Eclipse workspace and somehow Makefile module of Eclipse cannot build the project now. It gives the following error:

```
g++: error: /src/main: No such file or directory
```

Whereas there should have been

```
g++ -I $(APR_INCLUDE) -I $(CMS_HOME)/src/main
```

which uses two make variables. I already put them before this line and define them as :

```
export APR_INCLUDE=/usr/include/apr-1
export CMS_HOME=~/Desktop/activemq-cpp-library-3.8.4
```

Same Makefile is fine with console, but not with Eclipse, which is weird.

Any thoughts?

Here is where I put my export lines:

```
obstacleDetection_cpp: src/obstacleDetection.cpp protoc_middleman
    export APR_INCLUDE=/usr/include/apr-1
    export CMS_HOME=~/Desktop/activemq-cpp-library-3.8.4
    g++ -I  $(APR_INCLUDE) -I $(CMS_HOME)/src/main -g -o src/obstacleDetection.o -c src/obstacleDetection.cpp
    cd libs && cp $(CMS_HOME)/src/main/.libs/libactivemq-cpp.so.18.0.4 . && ln -sf libactivemq-cpp.so.18.0.4 libactivemq-cpp.so.18
    g++ -L $(CMS_HOME)/src/main/.libs/ -g -o bin/obstacleDetection src/obstacleDetection.o src-gen/Point.pb.cc src-gen/Point.pb.h -lactivemq-cpp -lssl -lprotobuf -pthread
    @echo "Success. Run the executable from the binary directory with: LD_LIBRARY_PATH=../libs/ ./obstacleDetection"
```

Comment: Eclipse may clear the environment, you should probably add the variable in the project settings.

Comment: I do not have the binary created in the settings since it does not even compile, therefore I cannot set the environment variable in run configurations.

Comment: You need to be very careful with your terminology.  Do you really mean _environment_ variables?  Or do you mean _make_ variables?  Do the export lines appear in your shell configuration such as `~/.bashrc` (environment variables)?  Or do they appear in your makefile (make variables)?

Comment: You put those `export` lines in the makefile? Where in the makefile? In the make context? In a recipe?

Comment: @EtanReisner Those are in my Makefile yes. I am editing the question, and putting the place where I am using them.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg I tried adding them to Build Variables and also Environment Variables, both did not work.

Comment: @MadScientist They are not in my bashrc file no, this means they aren't environment variables, right?

Comment: It should be easy to see if it is a makefile variables or not, just search for it in the makefile. Also, environment variables are usually set in the bash profile file (`~/.profile` or `~/.bash_profile` or something similar).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not right:

```
obstacleDetection_cpp: src/obstacleDetection.cpp protoc_middleman
        export APR_INCLUDE=/usr/include/apr-1
        export CMS_HOME=~/Desktop/activemq-cpp-library-3.8.4
        g++ $(APR_INCLUDE) -I $(CMS_HOME)/src/main ...
```

All lines in the recipe (that is, lines that are indented with a TAB in a target context like this) are passed to the shell.  These are not make variable assignments.  There are two things wrong with that:

First, each logical line in the recipe is passed to a new shell.  That means any changes to the process context (such as the environment or the working directory) are present only for the duration of that logical line; once the shell processing that line exits, all those changes are lost.  So, these lines have no impact: they set an environment variable in the shell, then the shell exits and that setting is gone.

Second, the variable references you make in your compile line, such as `$(APR_INCLUDE)`, are *make* variable references, not environment variable references.  So even if those environment variable assignments still had effect, they would not be used because you're not referring to environment variables here.

You want to create *make* variable assignments.  That can only be done *outside* of a recipe.  Also, you don't need to export them because only make needs to see them (make will expand them before invoking the shell).  So, your makefile should look like this:

```
APR_INCLUDE = /usr/include/apr-1
CMS_HOME = $(HOME)/Desktop/activemq-cpp-library-3.8.4

obstacleDetection_cpp: src/obstacleDetection.cpp protoc_middleman
        g++ -I  $(APR_INCLUDE) -I $(CMS_HOME)/src/main -g -o src/obstacleDetection.o -c src/obstacleDetection.cpp
        cd libs && cp $(CMS_HOME)/src/main/.libs/libactivemq-cpp.so.18.0.4 . && ln -sf libactivemq-cpp.so.18.0.4 libactivemq-cpp.so.18
        g++ -L $(CMS_HOME)/src/main/.libs/ -g -o bin/obstacleDetection src/obstacleDetection.o src-gen/Point.pb.cc src-gen/Point.pb.h -lactivemq-cpp -lssl -lprotobuf -pthread
        @echo "Success. Run the executable from the binary directory with: LD_LIBRARY_PATH=../libs/ ./obstacleDetection"
```

Comment: Thanks, this solved the problem. And yes, these were not environment variables, I have edited the question.